# Ajax not sending value even in console shows the value and the url

Tags: ajax

this is the script that gave me a headache and still couldn't figure out the issue

```
 <script>
    function loadSubcategories() {
        var categorySelect = document.getElementById("category");
        var selectedCategory = categorySelect.value;

        // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Define the PHP file to call and the HTTP request method
        var url = "cgi-bin/get_subcategories.php";
        var method = "POST";

        // Set up the request
        xhr.open(method, url, true);

        // Set the request header (if needed)

        // Define the callback function
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Update the subcategory dropdown with the response from the PHP file
                var subcategorySelect = document.getElementById("subcategory");
                subcategorySelect.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                alert(xhr.responseText);
        return;
            }
        };

        // Send the request with the selected category
        console.log("XHR URL: " + url);
        console.log("XHR Data: " + "category=" + selectedCategory);
        xhr.send("category=" + selectedCategory);
    }
</script>
```

Even tho the console shows the value and the url but the PHP just reply (is script is running) and error (No category parameter received.)

```
    <?PHP
 echo "Script is running"; 
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  {
 $category = $_POST['category'];

 echo $category;
 }
 } else {
 // Handle the case when "category" is not set
 echo "No category parameter received.";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: anyone see something i cant see ? lol

Answer (score 1):

ok found the solution to this crazy bug, set up a header right after you set up the request
the code line look like this

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
 urlencoded");
```

so the ajax script should look like this

```
 <script>
    function loadSubcategories() {
        var categorySelect = document.getElementById("category");
        var selectedCategory = categorySelect.value;

        // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Define the PHP file to call and the HTTP request method
        var url = "cgi-bin/get_subcategories.php";
        var method = "POST";

        // Set up the request
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
      urlencoded");
        // Set the request header (if needed)

        // Define the callback function
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        // Update the subcategory dropdown with the response 
                var subcategorySelect = 
                document.getElementById("subcategory");
                subcategorySelect.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                alert(xhr.responseText);
        return;
            }
        };

        // Send the request with the selected category
        console.log("XHR URL: " + url);
        console.log("XHR Data: " + "category=" + selectedCategory);
        xhr.send("category=" + selectedCategory);
    }
</script>
```